# printing an equal number of character per line

Tags: c, printf

i have a c printf program like this

```
for (r = 0; r <= 100 ; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c <= 100 ; c++) {

             printf("A");
        }
    }
```

how do i edit the code such that it would print 5 "A" per line such as

"AAAAA" but multiple line

Comment: Print a newline character after each 5 `A`s...

Comment: @Newbie ICT IS  It is a discrimination of other letters in the alphabet! I reject!

Comment: Clarify your otherwise-foggy question. For your given loop(s), do you expect (a) twenty lines of five `'A'` each, therefore 100 characters total , or (b) eighty lines of five `'A'` each, therefore 400 characters total, excluding newlines. I *think* you want (b), but it should be noted in your question.

Comment: `for (c = 0; c <= 100 ; c++) printf("A");` prints 101 `'A'`.  Is that your intent?

Answer (score 2):

Check if the division c / 5 returns in a remainder of 0.

```
for (r = 0; r <= 20 ; r++) {
    for (c = 0; c <= 20 ; c++) {
        if (c%5 == 0) 
            printf("\r\n");
        printf("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: Suspect you want `printf("A");` before `if (c%5 == 0) 
            printf("\r\n");`

Comment: But.... `c` is starting at 0. So when having `c == 4` it will print its 5th `A`. With the next iteration it has to do a linebreak before printing. Where's my mistake?

Comment: Yes, suggestion was a bit off.  `if (c%5 == 0) 
            printf("\r\n");` prints an `\n` before anything is printed and no `\n` after the last `A`.  Perhaps use `if (c%5 == (5-1)) ...` after the `printf("A");`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reduce the amount of columns to 5 and print a newline after each column cycle ends like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 20; ++row) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 5; ++column) {
         printf("A");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of printed letters is a multiple of 5, print a `'\n'`

```
void NuBePrint(int rows, int cols, int period, char letter) {
  long count = 0;
  // OP may really want `r < rows` and `c < cols` to print 100x100 rather than 101x101
  for (int r = 0; r <= rows ; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c <= cols; c++) {
      putchar(letter);
      count++;
      if (count%period == 0) putchar('\n');
    }
  }
  if (count%period != 0) putchar('\n');  // Cope with last line
}

// sample usage 
NuBePrint(100, 100, 5, 'A');
```